# MongoDB - Find() by _id is taking so long - planSummary:IDHACK (timeAcquiringMicros is equal to query time)

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know why the query below is taking so long (21 seconds) to execute even though the collection just have one document. I have a replicaset PSA instance with 130 databases giving a total of 500K files between collections and indexes (350GB). The Linux server has 32GB RAM and 8 CPUs, but we are not having IO and CPU bound. I'm using MongoDB 3.2 with Wiredtiger engine.

What is the relation between timeAcquiringMicros and the query time?

```
2019-10-03T11:30:34.249-0300I COMMAND[
   conn370659
]command bd01.000000000000000000000000 command:find{
   find:"000000000000000000000000",
   filter:{
      _id:ObjectId('000000000000000000000006')
   },
   batchSize:300
}planSummary:IDHACK
    keysExamined:1
    docsExamined:1
    idhack:1
    cursorExhausted:1
    keyUpdates:0
    writeConflicts:0
    numYields:0
    nreturned:1
    reslen:102226
locks:{
   Global:{
      acquireCount:{
         r:2
      }
   },
   Database:{
      acquireCount:{
         r:1
      },
      acquireWaitCount:{
         r:1
      },
      timeAcquiringMicros:{
        r:21893874
      }
   },
   Collection:{
      acquireCount:{
         r:1
      }
   }
}protocol:op_query 21894ms
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB uses [multiple granularity locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_granularity_locking) to help improve parallelism. There are some operations that need to lock on the Global, Database, or Collection level.

Your query you see several `acquireCount: { r: X }` the `r` is attempting to obtain an "intent shared lock" which is just a way of saying I don't need to lock anyone out, but I want to obtain a loose lock on a read at each of these levels before I get to the level I need. This prevents your query from executing while their are exclusive writes happening at any level you need to go through.

Importantly for you, you saw this:

```
   Database:{
      acquireCount:{
         r:1
      },
      acquireWaitCount:{
         r:1
      },
      timeAcquiringMicros:{
        r:21893874
      }
```

Meaning it took 21893874 milliseconds to acquire the lock you wanted at the *Database* level. Your query made it through the Global level, but was blocked by something that had an exclusive lock at the Dattabase level. I recommend becoming acquainted with this table in the MongoDB documentation: [What locks are taken by some common client operations?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-locks-are-taken-by-some-common-client-operations).

One hypothesis in your situation is that someone had decided to create an index in the foreground on the database. This is interesting because you usually create indices on collections, but you need an exclusive write lock on the database which locks all your collections in that database.

Another hypothesis is that your database is just under heavy load. You'll need something like Percona's MongoDB Prometheus Exporter to scrape data from your database, but if you are able to get the data another way these two blog posts can help you understand your performance bottleneck.

[Percona Monitoring and Management (PMM) Graphs Explained: WiredTiger and Percona Memory Engine](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/02/27/percona-monitoring-and-management-pmm-graphs-explained-wiredtiger-and-percona-memory-engine/)

[Percona Monitoring and Management (PMM) Graphs Explained: MongoDB MMAPv1](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/02/28/percona-monitoring-and-management-pmm-graphs-explained-mongodb-mmapv1/)